# Verb Meaning to Process Energy?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm picturing 'energy' here in the context of holding a physical ball of siphoned energy. What is a good verb to encapsulate the overall, general concept of turning, or processing that vibrant energy, into something else? 'Combust' has too much of a fiery feel. 'Transform' and 'process' feel a little vague and lacklustre: they don't quite capture the sense that we're dealing with energy as opposed to something a little less intense. Are there some more abstract verbs that readily capture this idea, or perhaps some more common ones I'm forgetting?

In an example sentence: "Joseph _____ the energy he had gathered into something new."

Comment: See [writers.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, I would use the verb **channel**. It's often heard together with 'energy'.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/channel) gives this definition:

> 1. Direct towards a particular end or object.
>      *‘the council is to channel public funds into training schemes’*

And [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/channel) gives the following examples:

> 5) If you **channel your energies** or emotions into something, you concentrate on or do that one thing, rather than a range of things.
>   *Stephen is **channelling his energies** into a novel called Blue. [VERB noun + into]*
>
> Synonyms: direct, guide, conduct, transmit

So your sentence would be:

> Joseph **channelled** the energy he had gathered into something new.